# How to unittest assertDictNotEqual?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-unittest

I wrote a contextlib that update environment variable and for unittest wrote test as:

```
previous_env = copy.deepcopy(os.environ)
with MYContext() as my_context:
    with self.assertRaises(AssertionError):
        self.assertDictEqual(dict(os.environ), dict(previous_env))
self.assertDictEqual(dict(os.environ), dict(previous_env))
```

But I wonder if I can do better than the use of `with self.assertRaises(AssertionError)` to assert on dict difference ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a [ticket](https://bugs.python.org/issue8038) in the Python bugtracker, related to missed methods in the `unittest` module. Here is the quote from the discussion:

> Hi,
>
> I am the original reporter of the bug. Please forgive me if this is
>   not the place for discussing the issue.
>
> I've thought about it, and **stuff like assertDictNotEqual or
>   assertSequenceNotEqual aren't really necessary - it is much easier
>   (and shorter) to use assertNotEqual**, and there's no need for any
>   special formatting needed to say that something is equal when it
>   shouldn't.
>
> This is not the case for assertNotRegexpMatches, though.
>   assertNot(re.match(...)) tells me only that False is not True. I'd
>   like it to say *how* the text matches the regex (the matching part
>   that is). (Sorry for repeating myself, I try to be clearer this time.)
>
> So, this issue could be renamed to "Implement assertNotRegexpMatches."

And, as for me, I don't think if `assertDictNotEqual` could be useful, since there is **exactly one case**, when the assert could fail. You should just use [`assertNotEqual`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertNotEqual)